# UK visa application withdrawal and reapplying

Tags: uk-visa

Do any one of you have experience withdrawing an UK Tier 2 visa application? If so I have some questions.

1. Does it affect the chances of getting a visa when you reapply?
2. When reapplying should you disclose that you have previously
   withdrawn an application? If so in what way should you disclose?
   **(Given that there is no specific question on the visa application
   form asking whether the applicant has previously withdrawn an
   application)**.
3. Will **UKVI** look at the previously withdrawn application (which
   contains incorrect documents) while making a decision on your
   current application?

Apologies for the multiple questions. These questions have been rarely asked and answered so thought this post can help someone in the future.

Comment: I’m no expert on this but I find it hard to believe UKVI would have time to spare to go through withdrawn applications when assessing a subsequent application. AFAIK a withdrawn application is exactly that. I also doubt errors in a withdrawn application could be permissible as grounds for refusal of a subsequent application.